# Are there any schools with packaging design specializations in the US?

Tags: education, packaging

Mohawk College in Ontario, CA just opened a very nice design center which includes packaging machinery for the students to learn, it is a part of their graphic design program. http://www.mohawkcollege.ca/

It got me wondering if there's any programs in the United States with a similar program and facilities. Does anyone know of one?

Comment: [Yes](https://www.google.com/search?q=academic+program+packaging+design).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UW-Stout, WI has a packaging engineering program:

http://www.uwstout.edu/programs/bsp/

Alas, it's not part of the art program, though that also has a good reputation:

http://www.uwstout.edu/programs/bfaa/

Answer (score 0):

I was doing more research and work today (one of the books I work in is about the industry) and saw an article in a magazine we barter with that had an article about the FFTA offering a Press Operator Certification Course. Went online and looked into it and found this:

https://www.flexography.org/

To avoid future Link Rot that goes to their main page where there's links to training and education.

Comment: Are you looking for a program in the graphic arts (typically includes press operators, print technology, packaging production, etc.) or visual arts (graphic design, etc.)? They are usually different degree tracks, though you could certainly double major or major/minor in both.

Comment: I'm looking for ones that specifically train students on packaging equipment, packaging design, flexopress printers, diecutters, folder/gluers, so on. While I wouldn't mind learning it myself I'm really not looking for me but for the book I work on.

Comment: Ah, well, that's probably not a Graphic Design question, then. The printing/packaging industry is much more of a mechanical engineering/trade school type background and is usually quite separate from that of the Art/Design programs. I don't think it necessarily SHOULD be that way, but it is. One term to research on would be "Graphic Communications Management"...which is a term used to describe the business and process of commercial printing (of which packaging would be a subset of).

Comment: Well as I said mostly. I am looking for myself as well if there's an online program or any MFA programs that are in schools with the facilities where I would be able to do both. I already have a bachelor's degree though.

Comment: Oh! Gotcha. Well, the Stout recommendation above would work. I believe they offer an MFA now and with both the printing and packaging programs, you should have access to a nice range of manufacturing technologies.

Comment: Link rot at your link

Answer (score 0):

Rochester Institute of Technology (RIT) has a print industry major program ( http://print.rit.edu/About_the_Center/ ) my father-in-law went there back in the 60s and actually did some research work on stochastic screening (or so he claims :O ).

Not sure if this qualifies, but University of the Arts in Philadelphia has had an Industrial Design department since the 19th century. In some cases package design is considered a subset if ID.

Answer (score 0):

[Fashion Institute of Technology](http://www.fitnyc.edu/2606.asp) in New York City has an amazing packaging design program!

Comment: Updated link to point directly to the packaging design program. Note that this appears to be a graphic design focused program (vs. a mechanical engineering program as the other answers mention).